# Alternative to hiding non-virtual members with new

Tags: c#, inheritance

Suppose I want to do something like this:

```
class Foo
{
    public event BarHandler Bar;
    ...
}

class FooList<T> : List<T> where T : Foo
{
    public override void Add(T item)
    {
        item.Bar += Bar_Handler;
        base.Add(item);
    }

    private void Bar_Handler ...

    ...
}
```

But `Add` in `List<T>` is not virtual, so I cannot use `override`, I would have to resort to `new` instead. This however does not provide polymorphism, and I am worried about subtle bugs that could be introduced by refering to `FooList` as simply `List`, which would lead to my Event-Handler not being added.

My current specific case of this is: I want to subclass `ObservableCollection` for Items that implement `INotifyPropertyChanged`, and add/remove an Event-Handler to those Items if they are added/removed. Then I provide an Event that is raised if any Item in Collection changes.

I would like a solution for my particular problem as well as the underlying general problem, as this is somethink I stumbled upon a few times, coming from a java background.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Instead of extending `List<T>` you could implement the [`IList<T>`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/5y536ey6%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) interface and hold an internal `List<T>` member variable. That way you don't break the existing `List<T>` functionality and still implement the same interface as `List<T>`.

Example:

```
class FooList<T> : IList<T> where T : Foo
{
    private List<T> m_internalList = new List<T>();

    public void Add(T item)
    {
        item.Bar += Bar_Handler;
        m_internalList.Add(item);
    }

    // other methods
}
```

Comment: Composition over Inheritance, now I feel stupid for not seeing it. thanks!

Comment: Oh that `m_` prefix makes me sad, but +1 ;)

Comment: And why does the `m_` prefix make you sad? Don't you like to separate your instance variables from your locals? ;-)

Comment: That bring c++ coding standard to c#. If at all you want to distinguish the field vs local variable, then use `this.internalList`.

Comment: @SriramSakthivel I guess it's something I just got used to... To me it's just faster to type `m_` instead of `this.`, but of course of have a valid point.

Answer (score 3):

`List<T>` is not intended to inherit and thus `Add` method isn't virtual, but [`Collection<T>`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms132397%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) is. You can inherit `Collection<T>` instead and override `InsertItem` method.

```
internal class MyCollection<T> : Collection<T> where T : Foo
{
    protected override void InsertItem(int index, T item)
    {
        item.Bar += Bar_Handler;
        base.InsertItem(index, item);
    }
}
```

Related: [Why not inherit from List<T>?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21692193/why-not-inherit-from-listt)

FWIW  [`ObservableCollection<T>`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms668604%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) class itself inherits `Collection<T>`.